# Drupal views: Group and concatenate field values

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

How to use group by and concatenate field values in Drupal 7 views 3.

**My Use case:** A user can have multiple subscriptions, each subscription will have a product related to it.

In my views I want to display the user name and the products which he is subscribed to.

My current view displays the field like this;

> Username 1 - product 1
>
> Username 1 - product 2
>
> Username 2 - product 1

I want this to be displayed like this;

> username 1 - product 1, product 2
>
> username 2 - product 1

I tried https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator this module, but couldn't achieve my requirement.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/693664

Comment: "One of the comment on above link"..

I was able to solve this using Views Aggregator Plus .

Go to your view, select Table with aggregation options as your Format.

Apply group function to Artist, set Group and Compress.
Apply group function to Artwork, set Enumerate and set the parameter to ', '

Works a treat!

Comment: do you solve your problem?